# ng-change on 'range' input calling multiple times in chrome

Tags: angularjs, html, range, angularjs-ng-change

If we change the range input by sliding, the `ng-change` function is getting called again and again till some other element is clicked.

This happens only in **chrome**. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25601/). Slide the element and move the mouse around.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Update Angular, 1.0 is very old.

Comment: @dfsq Tried with v1.5.7. Same

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine (but don't use alert).

Comment: Nope... works just fine. Your Fiddle, that is.

Comment: @dfsq  Really? which version are you using? I am using 49.0.2623.87 and the issue is reproducable

Comment: @MikkoViitala it is reproducble with chrome 49.0

Comment: I can reproduce it with `alerts` but it has nothing to do with Angular, it's totally unrelated. Try to use console.log instead.

Comment: @dfsq - Correct. If using console.log in fiddle, it is not happening. But It is reproducible in the code which I am working on and it does not have an alert.
It has something to do with focus of the element? or what is the reason for multiple calls when using an alert?

Comment: I think this is related to how browser manages UI thread tasks (?). Since it's single threaded it might get confused with type[range] and multiple change happening one after another. I think you should be able to fix it with ngModelOptions by adding some debounce. Try it.

Comment: @dfsq. If I open developer console and move the mouse around, fn is getting called multiple times, other wise only once. (??). something similiar with alerts. Will try with ngModelOptions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 } }"` on input element.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is obvious, 
 when you use alert in '**rangeChanged()**' because although you see the **alert** the '**range bar**' still has the **focus** , so when you move your mouse it tries to also move the 'range bar' left/right according to mouse movement ,and then you get again the 'alert box' and again and so on.

it is better to use another popup window to do the job and not the windows default alert.

Like bootstrap modal for example, link : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.
hope this help, good luck.